# Find a reduced Groebner basis

Tags: commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

> **Problem:** Let ideal $I = \langle f_1,f_2,f_3 \rangle \subset \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ in which $f_1 = x-3y-4z, f_2 = -x+y+6z-2, f_3 = x-z+2$.
>
> 1. Find a reduced Groebner basis of $I$ with lexicographic ordering.
> 2. Show that $g = -2y+14z-10-x^3+3x^2z-6x^2-3xz^2+12xz+z^3-6z^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[f_1,f_2,f_3]$.

**My attempt:** I have computed
\begin{cases} 
&x-3y-4z\\
&-x+y+6z-2\\
&x-z+2 
\end{cases}

$\Leftrightarrow$\begin{cases} 
x&-3y-4z\\
&-2y+2z-2\\
& 3y+3z+2 
\end{cases}

$\Leftrightarrow$\begin{cases} 
x-3y&-4z\\
-2y&+2z-2\\
&6z-1
\end{cases}

$\Leftrightarrow$\begin{cases} 
x+\frac{11}{6}\\
y+\frac{5}{6}\\
z-\frac{1}{6} 
\end{cases}

Let $g_1=x+\frac{11}{6},g_2=y+\frac{5}{6},g_3=z-\frac{1}{6}$, then $G = \{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ is a reduced Groebner basis. But I have used Maple to computed the reduced Groebner basis of $I$ and the result is $1$. Is my attempt true? Thank all!

Answer (score 0):

This is a system of linear equations whose unique solution is $x = -11/6$, $y = -5/6$ and $z = 1/6$, so it is easy to check that your answer is correct. (It is.)

> But I have used Maple to computed the reduced Groebner basis of I and the result is 1.

I do not know why this would happen. Maybe your input into Maple contained a typo.

Comment: Why do we get that answer from Maple??? I don’t think Maple was wrong and the reduced basis is unique.?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried Singular:

> ring r = 0, (x,y,z), lp;
>
> ideal i = x-3y-4z, -x+y+6z-2, x-z+2;
>
> std(i);

The result is

6z-1,

y-5z,

x-z+2.

For number 2, divide $g$ into the Groebner basis. Groebner bases have the property that $g$ lies in the ideal generated by the Groebner basis if and only if the remainder of the division is zero.

Comment: In maple: `> with(PolynomialIdeals): J := PolynomialIdeal(x-3*y-4*z, -x+y+6*z-2, x-z+2): with(Groebner): Basis(J, lex);` `[6 x + 11, 6 z - 1, 6 y + 5]`

Comment: Anyone help me in problem number $2$?

Comment: Added comment to my answer.